# Cannot install jq version 1.6 in Docker

Tags: docker, version, jq

Our Dockerfile uses `FROM python:3.7-slim-buster` as the base image. One of the lines in our dockerfile is `RUN apt-get install jq -y`. When we exec into a running container build off of this image, we get:

```
jq --version
jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe
```

Per https://stedolan.github.io/jq/, version 1.6 was released in 2018, and we'd like to use 1.6 in our app. When we try:

- `RUN apt-get install jq=1.6.0 -y` or `RUN apt-get install jq=1.6 -y`, we are met with errors
- `E: Version '1.6.0' for 'jq' was not found` and `E: Version '1.6' for 'jq' was not found`

When I run `jq --version` locally on my Mac, I receive `jq-1.6`. How can we get version 1.6 for our docker image?

Comment: Is using a different FROM base image an option for you?

Comment: Perhaps, but it is far from our first option. Sticking with version 1.5 of this library is probably preferred over changed the FROM base image.

Comment: `jq` is at 1.5 in Debian Buster ("stable"), but 1.6 in Bullseye ("testing") and Sid ("unstable").

Comment: So you're saying it isn't necessarily advised to use 1.6 yet?

Comment: `RUN apt-get install jq -y` works to install 1.6 in Bullseye as of Feb, 2022. `RUN apt-get install jq=1.6 -y` is still not working in Bullseye.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `jq` 1.6 in a Debian 10-based image, the simplest option is to download the statically-linked version provided by the project:

```
RUN curl -L -o /usr/bin/jq https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64
```

You might need to install `curl` first (using `apt`).

It’s usually poor form to install non-packaged binaries in `/usr/bin`, but I tend to think it’s less of a concern in a container image...